# How to run callback function from content script after loading page ? chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I want to run a callback function from content script after tab loading new page .

Here is my code :

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, callback) {
    if (request.id == "content_script") {
        // open google.com
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            "id" : "openUrl",
            "url" : "https://google.com"
        }, function(response) {
        });
        // call background script
        // go to the claim code page
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            "id" : "background"
        }, function() {
            alert("test");
        });
    }
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.id == "openUrl") {
        var tabId = sender.tab.id;
        var url = msg.url;
        openUrl(tabId, url);

    } else if (msg.id == "background") {
        setTimeout(function() {
            sendResponse();
        }, 5000);
    }

});

function openUrl(tabId, url) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {
        url : url,
        active : false
    }, function() {
        console.log("open tab url callback");
    });
};
```

I also uploaded the source code to google drive, you can download it using the bellow link :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=15zSn40z4zYkvCZ8B-gclzixvy6b0C8Zr

as you can see the alert test don't show !

However if I remove the code which open new url , then alert ("test") appear !

I am not sure why ! but it looks like javascript lost the reference to the call back function when I open new url .

How can I solve the problem ? what's the correct way ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `sendResponse` function becomes invalid after the message callback returns, **unless you return true** from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously. (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)

   Add `return true;` in background.js to make this handler asynchronous.
2. Now you get an error `Attempting to use a disconnected port object` in the `sendResponse();` call of background.js, and yes, that's a result of the page navigating away and losing the context that the content script was running in.

   There's no way to make this work: The context in which you wanted to call `alert()` simply doesn't exist anymore.

   Try using [chrome.tabs.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) instead. But this means you have to set up the listener at the top level, and not inside of any callback. Message passing is hard.